# Is there any way to update the props variable with dynamic action call in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, formik

Currently, I am working on a component where I am using state and city as separate dropdowns.
I also use the *Formik* for my form.

When a user updates state dropdown, first of all, we call the parent component's method, and then we call redux action and get the city details based on the *StateId*.

After that, we pass that city data to the child component as props.

Now when we Reset or Clear entire form data, At that time, We just clear *Formik* data, and our city drop-down value is also clear, but the props which we getting from the parent component is still there and display the dropdown values as it is.

Can anyone suggest, that which better way we can follow so that our issue will be resolved?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Sync the data of form and redux , when you are restting the data, inform redux also.

Comment: why don't you clear the `city` data and set it to empty when you clear/reset form data?

Comment: could you please share a example code?

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609944/discarding-changes-when-using-formik-with-react